# Kohana: Replacing %20 and space with +

Tags: php, kohana

After an HTTP request has been made in form of e.g. `mysite.com/controller/test%20url`, 
With Kohana, how can I create an auto-redirect to the same controller but %20 replaced with + (plus)?

Stackover flow does this. It replaces spaces with hyphens.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have any code you already tried?

Comment: This solution is not about the PHP code. It's about WHERE to put that code in Kohana. That's what I need. Otherwise code would be replace + redirect. But where it's gonna go? I don't want to put it in the controller and verify the raw url each time. There must be a proper place to put it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should go outside of your framework, in your server system using url rewrites. If you are using apache, use your .htaccess file.

Comment: Hey! Thank YOU so VERY MUCH! Thanks for the tip! 
Thanks to your tip I managed to perform the appropriate search and applied it.


RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (\s|%20)
RewriteRule ^([^\s%20]+)(?:\s|%20)+([^\s%20]+)((?:\s|%20)+.*)$ $1+$2$3 [N,DPI]
RewriteRule ^([^\s%20]+)(?:\s|%20)+(.*)$ /$1+$2 [L,R=301,DPI]